# using high scores on multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two storyboards in my game: the home page and the game itself. When a user gets a high score in the game i save it as their high score. How can i then take that high score to display it on the homepage without linking the view controllers to the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save highscore anywhere in your project

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"kHighscoreKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Retrieve highscore anywhere else in your project

```
NSUInteger highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"kHighscoreKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your do not find your score data important or sensitive use `NSUserDefaults`

**First scene:**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:yourHighScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

**Second scene:**

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
yourHighScore = [defaults integerForKey:@"HighScore"]
```